# Fluid Images in an HTML email

Tags: html, image, email, fluid-layout

I have been trying to code fluid images in my HTML emails, and everything I find does not seem to work. I have tried

**html**

```
<img src="http://image.e.writersstore.com/lib/fe9b15737567067576/m/2/11569swwheader.jpg" alt="Learn, Market, Network" width="600px" height="274" border="0" style="display:block;" />
```

**css**

```
img {         
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
}
```

and just about every variation of it, inline and everything, but I cannot get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the `<img>` tag you are using? Which email clients have you checked?

Comment: did you try img {         
   min-width: 100%;
} ?

Comment: The width of image will depend on the container width when mentioning in terms of percentages, make sure the parent container also has 100% width

Comment: <img src="http://image.e.writersstore.com/lib/fe9b15737567067576/m/2/11569swwheader.jpg" alt="Learn, Market, Network" width="600px" height="274" border="0" style="display:block;"  />

Comment: change `width="600px"` to `width="100%"`

Comment: Yes, I did try min-width

Comment: no on your image tag, that attribute will be overriding your stylesheet, you may also want to include the inline style on your image tag too

Comment: Pete- tried it, still doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my image tag, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is it in a table / container with a width set on it? can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your full template, it will be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes-the table is 600px to determine the width of the email

Comment: Ok the width is always going to be 600px then - if the table isn't fluid the image won't be either

Comment: IDK if I did this right, but here is the fiddle

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/m4mm2/)

Comment: Oh, you can't use media queries - only very simple css.  Read this: http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/

Comment: Argh! Ok well I have been trying to make these responsive emails since that's what my boss wants, and this is how I found to do them. Thanks for the link and all the help and maybe I can figure it out now.

Comment: One more questions: if I can't define my table at 600px in order to use fluid images, then how do I keep it the right size? I don't want it to be full-width, right?